# Secret Santa name picking without replacement

Tags: probability

Suppose we have 6 names in a hat and each person draws out a name with no replacement.  I am trying to work out the probability of any three (and only three) people each picking out their own name.

How do the odds change if you identify three specific people and wish to know the odds of each of those identified people picking out their own name?

Comment: Hint: [Derangement](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=derangement&rawformassumption=%7B%22C%22,+%22derangement%22%7D+-%3E+%7B%22MathWorld%22%7D)

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to count the permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ which have exactly three fixed points. There are $\binom{6}{3}$ ways to choose the three numbers which are fixed. Let's say $1,2,3$ are fixed. What is left is to count in how many ways we can permute $4,5,6$ without any fixed points. It's easy to see that only two ways are admissible:
$$4\rightarrow 5, 5\rightarrow 6, 6\rightarrow 4\hspace{1cm} \text{and}\hspace{1cm} 4\rightarrow 6, 6\rightarrow 5, 5\rightarrow 4$$
All the other permutations will have 1 or 3 fixed points. To obtain the probability, we divide by the total number of permutations of $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, which is $6!$ and we get
$$P=\dfrac{2\cdot\binom{6}{3}}{6!}=\dfrac{1}{18}$$
As for your other question, the 3 fixed points have already been determined, so we just remove the $\binom{6}{3}$ term.